# Can I use a Binding in a Triggers's value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, triggers

I have the following XAML markup:

```
<Style.Triggers>    
    <Trigger Property="StackPanel.Background" Value="{Binding Color}">                  
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>                        
                <VirtualizingStackPanel/>                        
            </Setter.Value> 
        </Setter>                                  
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

However, the above markup causes an error stating:

> A binding cannot be set on value property of type trigger.

I want to decide what color to set using a property `Color` that is defined in the view model.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: Use a DataTrigger? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'd write a [multi-value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) that returns true if all the values passed in are equal, then use it with a MultiBinding that has bindings to the two values you want to compare.

Comment: @Will DataTrigger.Value has to be a constant too.

Comment: Depending on the logic behind switching the panel it might still work.

Comment: "decide what color to set using the Property - 'Color' defined in the view model" - this can be formalized using a Setter, not a Trigger: `<Setter Property="StackPanel.Background" Value="{Binding Color}"/>`. Changing ItemsPanel depending on Color doesn't make sense to me at all